# double is null where posting to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, null, double

I had the following problem. In my database I have an attribute which type is "float". When I create the model with Entity Framework, the same attribute is represented by a "double" field.

Here's the thing. In the view, if I write for example "23,22" the data annotation says it is not a number, and if I write "23.22" passes the validation but the attribute's value is null when it gets to the controller.

Any idea why does it happen? I've been looking for information, but nothing useful yet.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I add the code where I use that attribute.

In the model class it is like this:

```
    public class TestObject{

         ....
         public Nullable<double> attribute { get; set; }
         ....
        }
```

In the view:

```
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.attribute)
```

And in the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Test(TestObject test)
    {
     ....
        return View();
    }
```

If I write "23.22", when I access the attribute value in the controller, it is null.

Comment: Can you post your model, action method and view? We'll be able to help you diagnose this issue further having seen those.

Comment: That looks fine, it must be an issue outside of the code mentioned. Can you post the full model/view?

Comment: I wonder if the name `attribute` might have some special meaning and this is confusing the model binder.  Just for kicks try changing the name of the property to something else.

Answer (score 1):

As a passible solution you may change jQuery culture to allow comma separetor instead dot. In this case double will be passed correctly.

```
//For example German culture uses comma. Just add this line:

    <script>
    Globalize.culture("de-DE");
    </script>
```

Comment: The answer itself was not helpful, but because of "Globalize" I started looking into that, and I found an approach that is working. Thanks.

Comment: @Rodrigo Having the same issue. What was the approach?